# Is "You added me, wasn't it?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, questions

> "You added me, wasn't it?"

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Isn't it the same as asking "Wasn't it you that added me?"? It kinda looks weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's odd and would be considered a mistake.  The "tag question" should be

> You added me, didn't you?

Since the question form is "Did you add me." and not "Wasn't it you that added me"

If you said

> It was you that added me, wasn't it?

That is a correct sentence.

According to Michael Harvey, adding 'isn't it?' or 'wasn't it?' after any positive statement to turn it into a question is often found in South Asian (e.g. Indian) dialect speech. Example: Your mother knows my cousin, isn't it? –

Comment: Adding 'isn't it?' or 'wasn't it?' after any positive statement to turn it into a question expecting an affirmative answer is a mistake in standard English, but often found in South Asian (e.g. Indian) dialect speech. Example: Your mother knows my cousin, isn't it?

Comment: So is it wrong? Don't English speakers often use it though?

Comment: I've certainly heard native English speakers use it. But as Michael Harvey said, *'it's a mistake in standard English'*.

Comment: In British 'street speak' or 'youth slang' people often say 'innit?' for this purpose, and it has spread across cultural and ethnic boundaries. It is not exactly 'wrong' (people do say it) but it is very informal or low-register indeed. It is the sort of thing [Ali G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_G) would say.